# Is wrapping code inside a function scope good enough security for js games?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I know putting all my js code in

```
(function() {  

})();
```

will prevent users from changing variables to cheat in my games, but I'm wondering if,

**1.** Can variables be changed with other methods, maybe extensions or cheat engine?

**2.** Can I still have multiple js files interacting with each other if they are all separately wrapped like this?

**3.** Is there a better way to have secure js games where you can't cheat?

Comment: Even using IIFEs will only make it marginally harder for an attacker to cheat. In the end, they can just send requests to your backend with modified data and not care about how you do it in JS at all.

Comment: Users can always add a breakpoint inside your IIFE and change the variables there (with the console) so this technique doesn't make your game safer.